# How do I fix Rails 6 deprecation warning with scoping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

After updating to rails 6, I came across this deprecation warning. How do I fix this?

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Class level methods will no longer inherit scoping
from `install` in Rails 6.1. To continue using the scoped relation, pass
it into the block directly. To instead access the full set of models, as
Rails 6.1 will, use `Shop::Theme.unscoped`.
```

```rb
  scope :install, -> (theme) {
    shop = proxy_association.owner
    shop.theme.unpublish! if shop.theme
    self.create!(
      name: theme.name,
      zip: theme.zip,
      theme_id: theme.id,
      role: theme.role,
      load_preset: theme.load_preset
    )
  }
```

Comment: That's not really a scope, that's just a strange way of writing a class method so why not just say `def self.install(theme)`?

Comment: @muistooshort It creates the method on top of the collection proxy. 

`shop.themes.install(theme)`

Comment: Still not a scope. You could have `def self.install(theme)` inside `Shop::Theme` and it would work the same. `scope` is (mostly) just a way to create class methods, it isn't magic, it just creates class methods that are supposed to behave in certain ways.

Comment: Alternatively, make it an extension method on the association: `has_many :themes do def install ... end end`.